# VSCode intellisense says boost::shared_ptr requires 2 args gazebo transport

Tags: shared-ptr, typedef, ros2, gazebo-simu

I am working with the c++ gazebo transport library (Ros2 Galactic, Gazebo 11 classic). I was confused as to why
`gazebo::transport::NodePtr` gives the error

`namespace "gazebo::transport" has no member "NodePtr"C/C++(135)`

I traced the error to gazebo/transport/TransportTypes.hh. This is the error.

Line: `typedef boost::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;`

Error: `too few arguments for variable template "boost::shared_ptr"`

This error is true for all the other typedefs in the file.
Filling in a second arg shows the suggestion `<typename Key, typename Object> shared_ptr`. Colcon build still works.I think it probably a ros/gazebo specific library which I have added to the vscode include paths which is causing this issue.
Any one got any idea which library is causing it/how to remove this issue?

Thanks

EDIT:
I have traced the problem to the boost regex library. boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp is the place where intellisense is fetching the definition of <key, object>

```
template <class Key, class Object>
class object_cache{
public:
    typedef std::pair< ::boost::shared_ptr<Object const>, Key const*> value_type;
    typedef std::list<value_type> list_type;
    typedef typename list_type::iterator list_iterator;
    typedef std::map<Key, list_iterator> map_type;
    typedef typename map_type::iterator map_iterator;
    typedef typename list_type::size_type size_type;
    static boost::shared_ptr<Object const> get(const Key& k, size_type l_max_cache_size);

private:
    static boost::shared_ptr<Object const> do_get(const Key& k, size_type l_max_cache_size);

    struct data
    {
        list_type   cont;
        map_type    index;
    };

    friend struct data;
};
```

For some reason, this object cache class is the source of the issue. I cannot remove it as it is a dependency of gazebo/physics/physics.hh. I am not sure if this is an issue with my setup or Intellisense. Is there a way I can remove this file from the Intellisense path?